# How to achieve 100% approval rating?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I bought my own copy of ACNL yesterday, and I was wondering how to achieve 100% approval rating? I'm doing everything I could think of, my brother said he got it in 1 day on his copy...  I really wanna start building some PWP's!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a list of the specific things you can do to get approval points:

> - Sell rubbish (cans, boots etc…) to Re-Tail - 1 point
> - Change the town tune - 3 points*
> - Change the town flag - 3 points*
> - Sell items to Re-Tail - 3 points*
> - Write on the bulletin board - 3 points*
> - Do jobs for residents - 3 points
> - Water flowers - 1 point
> - Pull weeds - 1 point
> - Donate to museum - 7 points*
> - Upgrade your tent to a house - 20 points*
>
> *Only obtain points the first time you do this

(via [BidoofCrossing](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/)'s "[How to Get a Perfect Approval Rating](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/39924088482/how-to-get-a-perfect-approval-rating)")

Comment: I think if you talk to isabelle she'll tell you one of the things you can still do for points

Comment: Doing resident jobs (make sure they are completable) is a great way to get points and get items. Two birds with one stone.

Answer (score -4):

Well you can help animal villagers, donate to the museum, and upgrade your house. You can also write letters and write on the bulletin board too, selling items at re-tail and other stuff. Hope this helps

You can also pick fleas off of villagers using a bug net, just swipe at them.